# laravel: После вызова update ресурсного контроллера белый экран

Tags: laravel, update

Проект использует фреймворк laravel.
Проблема состоит в следующем: создан ресурсный контроллер, создан шаблон blade, в шаблоне расположена форма. Пытаюсь вызвать маршрут update, появляется белый экран. Отладка показала, что не происходит вход в метод update. В методе update сейчас только код вывода на экран передаваемых параметров для отладки, т.к. до метода update дело не доходит.

Подскажите, в чем может быть причина?

```
    <form action="{{route('settings.update', $settings->all())}}" class="form">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')

        <input type="text" name="{{$settings[0]->name}}" value="{{$settings[0]->name}}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">

            Обновить

        </button>
    </form>
```

Метод update

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    dd($id);
    dd($request);
    return redirect()->route('settings.index');
}
```

Маршрут:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::resource('/settings', 'SettingsController');
```

Answer (score 2):

Ищи тут:

```
route('settings.update', $settings->all())
```

Маршрут `settings.update` имеет вид: `/settings/{id}`. То есть, вторым параметром надо передать идентификатор изменяемого объекта. А ты передаешь `$settings->all()`.

---

Подозреваю, что ты собираешься изменять значения всех настроек в одной форме. И вообще не собираешься как-либо работать с каждой из настройкой по отдельности (то есть, не будет странички для отображение только одной настройки, не будет странички для редактирования только одной настройки, не будет удаления какой-либо настройки).

В таком случае, тебе не нужен ресурсный контроллер. Просто сделай пару маршрутов:

```
Route::get('/settings', 'SettingsController@edit')->name('settings.edit');
Route::put('/settings', 'SettingsController@update')->name('settings.update');
```

Тогда для формирования значения `action` будет достаточно `route('settings.update')`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, буду копать в сторону в сторону посика маршрутов

Answer (score 2):

Resources создают роуты вида:

```
Route::prefix('settings')->group(function () {
      Route::get('/', 'SettingsController@index');
      Route::post('/', 'SettingsController@store');

      Route::prefix('{id}')->group(function () {
        Route::put('/', 'SettingsController@update');
        Route::delete('/', 'SettingsController@destroy');
      });
    });
```

Соответственно, чтобы достучаться до нужного тебе роута `Update`, надо лезть в settings/ и методом отправки `PUT`

В Вашем конкретном случае `route('settings/{id}')` достаточно, так как метод `PUT` в `Laravel` сам поймет что это `update`;

Comment: route('settings/{id}') не достаточно. Надо еще и сам id передать.

Comment: Route::resource для каждого маршрута задает имя. Использовать имя маршрута лучше, чем хардкорно прописанный путь.